# php's imap_fetch_overview() date field format as MySQL timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, imap

php's imap_fetch_overview() date key is a date format like this:

```
Thu, 22 Aug 2013 07:53:32 -0400
```

Yikes. Is it possible to customize the format of the date? I am not seeing anything in the docs so I assume not. What I need to do is convert this to MySQL's timestamp format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't customize an included PHP function/library without rewriting and recompiling source.  A class could be customized, or inherited and adjusted.  But in this case, what you can do is a simple `strtotime()` of the date/time.  Then convert it to MySQL datetime.

```
$array=imap_fetch_overview();
$unixTimestamp=strtotime($array['date']);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime function. This function returns unix timestamp.

```
<?php
    $timestamp=strtotime("Thu, 22 Aug 2013 07:53:32 -0400");
?>
```

You can use date function to create a new datetime format:

```
<?php
    echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime("Thu, 22 Aug 2013 07:53:32 -0400"));
?>
```

More information:

http://www.php.net/strtotime
http://www.php.net/date

Answer (score 1):

Beside `strtotime()` function we can also using `DateTime` class available at PHP. Just put the date string returned by imap_fetch_overview() to `DateTime` constructor. Example as follow:

```
<?php
    $result=imap_fetch_overview($mbox_stream,$emailnumber);
    $message_date=new DateTime($result[0]->date);//Put date result at DateTime constructor
    echo $message_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");//Formating the DateTime value to MySQL DATETIME format
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPs imap_fetch_overview also brings back the arrival date as Unix timestamp in the udate object.

Please also refer to the array of objects here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php

List of available objects in the resulting array:

```
subject - the messages subject
from - who sent it
to - recipient
date - when was it sent
message_id - Message-ID
references - is a reference to this message id
in_reply_to - is a reply to this message id
size - size in bytes
uid - UID the message has in the mailbox
msgno - message sequence number in the mailbox
recent - this message is flagged as recent
flagged - this message is flagged
answered - this message is flagged as answered
deleted - this message is flagged for deletion
seen - this message is flagged as already read
draft - this message is flagged as being a draft
udate - the UNIX timestamp of the arrival date
```